# Distribution of p-values in this thought experiment?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, clustering, p-value

I'm trying to check whether my clustering was informative above and beyond random clustering.  This is my thought experiment to do it, can someone help?

1. Suppose I have a large number, $N$, groups.
2. Suppose within a group $r$, I have $M_r$ (on average 20) observations,  $\; Y_{r,i}$.
3. Suppose I then randomly assign each observation within a group to 1 of two clusters.
4. Then I run a regression for each group and find whether cluster 2 or cluster 1 has a smaller mean.

   $$Y_{r,i}=\beta_{0} +\beta_{1}{\rm Clust2}_{g,i} + \varepsilon_{r,i} $$
5. Finally, I get the pvalues for all these regressions.

If the clusters were randomly generated, can I expect only 5% of the pvalues to be less than 5%?  Or should I expect more?

Comment: I simulated it and the answer seems to be that it should be 5%.  Regardless of the size of $N$ and $M_r$

Comment: This is a nice way to think through how analyses work & figure it out. I've learned an incredible amount over the years doing things like this. Nice job.

Comment: An interesting thing would be to think about the sampling distribution of the fraction of p-values < 5%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simulated it and the answer seems to be that it should be 5%, if you are making random assignments to clusters. Regardless of the size of $N$ and $M_r$.

in R Code:

```r
############################################
################################ random clustering thought experiment
N = 80
pvalues = numeric(0)


for(i in 1:10000){

  data = cbind(x=rnorm(N,0,1))
  set  = sample(data, N/2)
  data = cbind(data, cluster=as.numeric(data%in%set))
  summary(lm(data[,'x']~data[,'cluster']))$coefficients[2,4]     

  pvalues[i] = summary(lm(data[,'x']~data[,'cluster']))$coefficients[2,4]    
}
```

I then assess my own k-means clustering (on real—not random—data), and I find that 20% of the p-values are statistically significant, so we can think that the extra 15% is some measure of improvement over randomly clustering.

Comment: I'm confused - are you doing the k-means on the randomly generated data?  If so then I wouldn't consider the extra 15% an improvement...

Comment: No, the real data is not random.